# Dynamically Changing Frame of View Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uitextview, uicollectionviewcell

[image]

I have a `UICollectionView`. The `UICollectionViewCell` contains a `UITextView`. I want to dynamically change the frame of the `UITextView`. I use the following code. The problem is that sometimes this works, other times it doesn't and no change is made to the frame. I am not sure what the issue is.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("message_cell" , forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DisplayMessageCollectionViewCell

    if let messageText =  "testing" {
        let size = CGSizeMake(250, 1000)
        let options = NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesFontLeading.union(.UsesLineFragmentOrigin)
        let estimatedFrame = NSString(string: messageText).boundingRectWithSize(size, options: options, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14)], context: nil)

        if let user_id = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("userId") {
            if (user_id == "testing") {

                    cell.messageTextView.frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.width - estimatedFrame.width - 16 - 8, 0, estimatedFrame.width + 16, estimatedFrame.height + 20)

            }
            else {

                    cell.messageTextView.frame = CGRectMake(48 + 3, 0, estimatedFrame.width + 15, estimatedFrame.height + 20 )

            }
        }

    }



    return cell
}
```

Comment: Currently, do all the cells have a size 250 x 1000, even though their frame is being reset?

Comment: So there's no problem with resetting the frame?

Comment: The problem is that basically sometimes these changes to the frame are applied, and other times they are not.

Comment: is autolayout enabled for these messageTextView objects?

Comment: @Lahav I have provided a screenshot for what happens above. The chat bubble is defined in code and as you can see it works fine in both cases. The textbox holding the message is defined in storyBoard, however no constraints are applied to it there.

Comment: try setting `messageTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`

Comment: @Lahav tried it, doesn't change anything

Comment: Try adding layout constraints programmatically to each messageTextView. Also make sure that `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is still set to false. This should keep the textview in place, since usually just setting the frame isn't enough to guarantee that a view will be in the correct position.

Comment: What layout constraints do you think I should add though/

Comment: I'm not sure. That's something that you'll have to figure out. But it seems like the text is always drifting off too far to the right, so I would probably start by constraining the left boundary of the text to the left boundary its container (aka the green or gray box)

Comment: The green or gray box is created programmatically tho, it is assigned a frame as well, however this frame seems to always stay in place

Comment: Yes, so add the NSLayoutConstraint programmatically that connects the box to the text, so that they don't drift apart

Comment: Yes except I'm not sure how to do that

Comment: [Here](http://iosdeveloperzone.com/2014/10/06/simplifying-autolayout-code-with-swift/) is an example

Comment: No, I know how to add constraints, but I don't know which constraints I would need to add here to create that behaviour

Comment: You'll have to figure that out. Start adding them and see what happens.

Comment: You want me to start adding random constraints...that won't help

Comment: Not random. Think about which ones are needed and which ones aren't

Comment: I don't know which ones are and which ones aren't, that's why I posted a question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113258/discussion-between-lahav-and-mankee).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed [Here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113258/discussion-between-lahav-and-mankee),

Adding trailing and leading NSLayoutConstraints to the `messageTextView` fixed the problem

Answer (score 1):

If you are using AutoLayout just remove the width and height constraints on the text components and it will adapt accordingly to the text size.

Next thing you should do is to calculate the textSize of the string in

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(yourCellWidth, FLT_MAX);

CGSize expectedLabelSize = [yourString sizeWithFont:yourLabelFont constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize lineBreakMode: UILineBreakModeWordWrap];   
    return expectedLabelSize;
}
```

NOTE: If you don't have SizeClasses checked it will show you the yellow warnings because you don't have width and height set, but just ignore them.

UPDATE: You can find a good tutorial about this topic [here](http://theappspace.com/dynamic-text-height-using-adaptive-layout/).